# Please explain how this code removes noise from an image

Tags: c, image-processing

How does the code below actually remove noise from an image? I'm trying to understand what's going on, but can't seem to grasp the overall idea. I have tried it and it works (but not well). Please give a rough explaination. Thank you.

```
void averageFilter(PIXEL_ARRAY* img, PIXEL_ARRAY* orig_img, int N) 
{

  int i, j, n, m;
  int red_avg, blue_avg, green_avg;
  int radius, out_of_bounds, idx, curr_idx;
  int32_t pixel;

  if (N % 2 == 0) {
    printf("ERROR: Please use an odd sized window\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  radius = N / 2;

  for (i = 0; i < img->sizeY; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < img->sizeX; j++) {
      out_of_bounds = 0;

      red_avg = 0;
      blue_avg = 0;
      green_avg = 0;

      for (n = i - radius; n <= i + radius; n++) {

    for (m = j - radius; m <= j + radius; m++) {
      if (n < 0 || m < 0 || n >= img->sizeY || m >= img->sizeX) {
        out_of_bounds++;
        continue;
      }
      idx = m + n * img->sizeX;
      /* Shift, mask and add */


      red_avg += ((orig_img->data[idx] >> 16) & 0xFF);
      green_avg += ((orig_img->data[idx] >> 8) & 0xFF);
      blue_avg += (orig_img->data[idx] & 0xFF);

    }
      }

      /* Divide the total sum by the amount of pixels in the window */
      red_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);
      green_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);
      blue_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);

      /* Set the average to the current pixel */
      curr_idx = j + i * img->sizeX;
      pixel = (red_avg << 16) + (green_avg << 8) + blue_avg;
      img->data[curr_idx] = pixel;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < img->sizeY; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < img->sizeX; j++) {`
```

For ever pixel in the grid...

```
for (n = i - radius; n <= i + radius; n++) {
 for (m = j - radius; m <= j + radius; m++) {
```

Visit the locations within `radius` of our pixel...

```
 if (n < 0 || m < 0 || n >= img->sizeY || m >= img->sizeX) {
        out_of_bounds++;
        continue;
```

(and remember how many we found)

```
  idx = m + n * img->sizeX;
```

When we find a location, we're

- `n` pixels up (main-pixel-Y +/- radius),
- `m` pixels across (main-pixel-X +/- radius),
  so...
- `n` rows of sizeX pixels,
- plus `m` for this row, is...

`idx`:  the pixel index of our location

```
 red_avg += ((orig_img->data[idx] >> 16) & 0xFF);
 green_avg += ((orig_img->data[idx] >> 8) & 0xFF);
 blue_avg += (orig_img->data[idx] & 0xFF);
```

Tally up the original image's RGB data from each location we visit

```
   /* Divide the total sum by the amount of pixels in the window */
   red_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);
   green_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);
   blue_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);
   /* Set the average to the current pixel */
```

...average all the locations within `radius` of each main-pixel...

```
      curr_idx = j + i * img->sizeX;
      pixel = (red_avg << 16) + (green_avg << 8) + blue_avg;
      img->data[curr_idx] = pixel;
```

...and set main-pixel-index in the output file to the average.

Answer (score 1):

The code explores the neighbourhood of each pixel, finds the average value of each R,G,B component, and writes them to the output image. So it's a smoothing filter. I have commented the code:

```
void averageFilter(PIXEL_ARRAY* img, PIXEL_ARRAY* orig_img, int N) 
{

  int i, j, n, m;
  int red_avg, blue_avg, green_avg;
  int radius, out_of_bounds, idx, curr_idx;
  int32_t pixel;

  if (N % 2 == 0) {
    printf("ERROR: Please use an odd sized window\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  radius = N / 2;                                   // distance from pixel to explore

  for (i = 0; i < img->sizeY; i++) {                // parse each image pixel
    for (j = 0; j < img->sizeX; j++) {
      out_of_bounds = 0;

      red_avg = 0;                                  // init the averages
      blue_avg = 0;
      green_avg = 0;

      for (n = i - radius; n <= i + radius; n++) {  // within the area to explore

    for (m = j - radius; m <= j + radius; m++) {
      if (n < 0 || m < 0 || n >= img->sizeY || m >= img->sizeX) {   // off the map?
        out_of_bounds++;                            // count pixels off the map
        continue;                                   // and skip the summing
      }
      idx = m + n * img->sizeX;        // locate index of the pixel in source 1D array
      /* Shift, mask and add */


      red_avg += ((orig_img->data[idx] >> 16) & 0xFF);   // extract each R,G,B in the region
      green_avg += ((orig_img->data[idx] >> 8) & 0xFF);  // and sum them
      blue_avg += (orig_img->data[idx] & 0xFF);

    }
      }

      /* Divide the total sum by the amount of pixels in the window */
      red_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);           // produce an average R,G,B within the region
      green_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);
      blue_avg /= (N * N - out_of_bounds);

      /* Set the average to the current pixel */
      curr_idx = j + i * img->sizeX;                // locate index in destination array
      pixel = (red_avg << 16) + (green_avg << 8) + blue_avg;  // merge the components
      img->data[curr_idx] = pixel;                  // set its value to the average of the region
    }
  }
}
```